# PyQt5 почему не отображается значок вызываемого окна после компоновки в -ехе?

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5, icon

```py
# Вызываемое окно:

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1100, 600)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('flag.ico')) #после компоновки не работает, при тесте работает!!!
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
def setWindowIcon(self, param):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Компоновка питона в ехе - это создание самораспаковывающегося с вашим кодом и библиотеками. Этот архив распаковывается в темп и оттуда исполняется.

Нужно или добавить иконку при компоновке или положить её в ресурс qrc

Comment: Ясно. Благодарю, но будет без иконки значит, раз это так все странно работает, и как сделать не ясно...  при компоновке там только иконка ярлыка программы на рабочем столе, и она работает... но в рамках окон ничего не работает... для чего тогда эти куча вариантов как прикрепить эту иконку, а в итоге она не работает... я в шоке, очень странные дела.